# ord() and Unicode Table don't give the same number

Tags: python

According to the Python documentation, ord() gives the corresponding number in Unicode. When I entered

```
ord('A')
```

I got the number 65. However, when I checked the Unicode number for 'A' in the site called Unicode Table (http://unicode-table.com/en), it says the number is 41.

Why is that happening? What is the correct reference guide to Unicode？

Answer (score 10):

"41" is in hexadecimal.

```
>>> ord("A")
65
>>> hex(ord("A"))
'0x41'
>>> int("41",base=16)
65
```

Note that along the top of the page you linked, you see `0123456789ABCDEF`, which is giving you the last digit.

Comment: Thank you! What base does Python use?

Comment: Base 10, in terms of default integer output.  If you want to enter numbers in binary, octal, or hexadecimal, you can do things like `0b101011` or `0o12364` or, as here, `0x41`.  `print 0x41` should give you 65.  (There's also one annoying misfeature of Python 2, where if a number simply starts with 0, it's interpreted as octal: try `print 010`, for example, which gives 8.)

Answer (score 0):

ord() function, at least in Python, is being used based on ASCII table.

Here is the [link](http://www.asciitable.com/) to the table.

In the table, you can easily tell the difference between hexadecimal and ASCII code.

Now to give you my own understanding, and as @DSM mentioned explicitly, ASCII code is the base-10 decimal version of an hexadecimal (forgive my poor English skills). Since, by convention or something else, the two-digit numbers after 7F in hex, is considered to be negative, you don't see hex version of the ASCII numbers after 127.

Comment: There are no ASCII characters above 127 regardless.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams there are but they are extended.

Comment: "Extended ASCII" is a misnomer. They are instead specific code pages.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams what do you mean by another specific code pages?